# Search and Select from Dropdown Autofocus problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleSelectionChange(selectElement, nextField) {
      nextField.focus();
    }
    
    function handleKeyPress(event, currentField, nextField) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        nextField.focus();
      }
    }
  </script>
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="incoming.php" method="post" >
                                            
<input type="hidden" name="pt" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $_GET['invoice']; ?>" />
<select name="product"  onchange="handleSelectionChange(this, qty)" style="width:300px; "class="chzn-select" required autofocus>
<option></option>
    <?php
    try {
        include('../connect.php');
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
        $result->execute();
    
        // Rest of your code to generate dropdown options
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Database Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['product_code']; ?> - <?php echo $row['gen_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?> | Expires at: <?php echo $row['expiry_date']; ?></option>
    <?php
                }
            ?>
</select>
<input type="number" onkeydown="handleKeyPress(event, this, price1)" name="qty"  value="" min="1" placeholder="Qty" autocomplete="off" style="width: 300px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" / required>
<input type="hidden" name="discount" value="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" />
<input type="number" onkeydown="handleKeyPress(event, this, button)" name="price1" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Price" style="width: 300px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" / required>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date("m/d/y"); ?>" />
<Button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 123px; height:35px; margin-top:-5px;" /><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Add</button>
</form>
```

Problem is that i want to autofocus on select element when page loads. But here autofocus is not working. I experimened that when I remove "class="chzn-select" from select tag, Autofocus works but when I add it it stop working. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First add id attribute to product select and then add

```
document.getElementById("product").focus()
```

on top of the script section.
Note that i removed php code, you can add php code in your code.

```js
document.getElementById("product").focus()

function handleSelectionChange(selectElement, nextField) {
  nextField.focus();
}
    
function handleKeyPress(event, currentField, nextField) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    nextField.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="incoming.php" method="post" >                                                
    <input type="hidden" name="pt" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="" />
    <select name="product" id="product"  onchange="handleSelectionChange(this, qty)" style="width:300px; "class="chzn-select" required>
        <option>Prod1</option>
        <option>Prod2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" onkeydown="handleKeyPress(event, this, price1)" name="qty"  value="" min="1" placeholder="Qty" autocomplete="off" style="width: 300px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" />
    <input type="number" onkeydown="handleKeyPress(event, this, button)" name="price1" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Price" style="width: 300px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="" />
    <Button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 123px; height:35px; margin-top:-5px;" /><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Add</button>
</form>
```